# Automatic generation of automatic tests?

Tags: maven

Is there some project which would generate template for automatic tests from api generation from Swagger in Java Spring? Something like one test file with one test for every put/get/delete/post for every enpoind in yaml definition with pregenerated json parameters.

If tehre is no such thing what approach would be reasonable to achieve something like this?

I tried to google something like that but I was not able anything close to this concept.

Solution should be simmilar to swagger itself. Something which could be integrated with maven so when the endpoints are generated from swagger definitons it would generate templates for the same endpoints which was generated.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! As we don't cater "best approaches" or [code fragments](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), can you please **[edit]** your question to add missing details specifying your requirements for the software you're looking for? E.g. is it a Java library or a Linux desktop application, what features should it provide, how much may it cost… For a guide, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185). Thanks!